# Правильное алгебраическое сложение

Tags: математика, линейная-алгебра

Есть статья на хабре https://habr.com/ru/post/335906/

Я пытаюсь понять как получается что `P(-1,4)+Q(1,2)=(1,-2)`
Не пойму откуда у них на выходе такое значение
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: там выше есть объяснение: _`(Xp, Yp)+(Xq,Yq) = (Xr, -Yr)`_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не много внимательности и (xr, -yr)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]